# "Exploring GridDB's Python Functions: Sending and Verifying Data Transmission to the Server"

Tags: python, griddb

Is there a pre-defined function available in GridDB for Python that can accomplish the same task as the code previously provided, which sends data to a GridDB server and receives a response indicating whether the data was successfully sent or not?

```
import griddb_python as griddb

# Set up the connection to the GridDB server
factory = griddb.StoreFactory.get_instance()
gridstore = factory.get_store(
    host="x",
    port=6548,
    cluster_name="x",
    username="x",
    password="x"
)

# Set up the container to store data
container_name = "x"
con_info = griddb.ContainerInfo(
    container_name,
    [["message_id", griddb.Type.STRING],
     ["message_text", griddb.Type.STRING]],
    griddb.ContainerType.COLLECTION, True
)
container = gridstore.put_container(con_info)

# Define the data to send
message_id = "1"
message_text = "Hello, World"
data = [message_id, message_text]

# Insert the data into the container
row = container.create_row()
row.set_field(0, data[0])
row.set_field(1, data[1])
container.put_row(row)

# Check if the data was successfully sent to the server
query = container.query("SELECT * WHERE message_id = '1'")
rs = query.fetch()
if rs.has_next():
    print("Data sent successfully.")
else:
    print("Error: data not sent.")

# Close the connection to the GridDB server
gridstore.close()
```